# Добрый день, не могу розшифровать JS

Tags: javascript

Сразу стоит сказать, что я полный новичок в этом деле. Так что не судите строго, если не корректно задаю вопрос.
Попался мне на днях такой код, вот часть его, как пример:

```
É=-~-~[],ó=-~É,Ë=É<<É,þ=Ë+~[];Ì=(ó-ó)[Û=(''+{})[É+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+([].ó+'')[ó-É]+(!!''+'')[ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[É]+(''+{})[É+ó]+({}+'')[ó+ó]+(''+{})[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó-É]][Û];Ì(Ì((!''+'')[ó-É]+(!''+'')[ó]+(!''+'')[ó-ó]+(!''+'')[É]+((!''+''))[ó-É]+([].$+'')[ó-É]+'\''+''+'\\'+(ó-É)+(É+É)+(ó-É)+'\\'+(þ)+(É+ó)+'\\'+(ó-É)+(ó+ó)+(ó-
```

Если я правильно понял, это шифрованый JS
Пробовал пользоваться https://beautifier.io/  не помогло(предполагаю что из-за моей "высокой квалификации").
Если есть идеи, дайте знать пожалуйста, в каком направлении искать?

Comment: К сожалению, код не полный. Поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код сравнительно легко отыскать. Там же и инструкции: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/how-can-i-deobfuscate-this-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы дешифровать данный код, необходимо открыть консоль браузера, вставить весь код, в конце кода предположительно 2 символа `()` заменить их на `.toString()` и запустить код.
Источник: `https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22679/how-can-i-deobfuscate-this-javascript-code`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Исправил ответ

Comment: @andreymal Все работает 'https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Whf1/D4VYnYs8F'

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Автор в тексте вопроса написал - "Попался мне на днях такой код, вот часть его", код неполный, идею ему дали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как был минус от Вас так и остался

Comment: @Arcadiy Это не мой..